# Emulator Nexus5X Android 8.0 Instant App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-instant-apps

I want to try to launch an Instant App (*already deployed : like wish, or buzzfeed*).

Now, I use *Android Studio 3.0* to emulate a *Nexus 5X API 26* With *Android 8.0*, I got the *Instant App development SDK installed (1.1.0)*.

I have activated in *`Settings > Google > Instant App my account`* to use it. But when I'm searching with google for wish I cannot acceded to the Instant App (*it only launch the normal website*).

I tried :

- *Change the countries of my device with a VPN*
- *Change the Android Version 7.1*
- *I update google chrome (61.0.3163.98) and services (11.5.18)*
- *I changed the device with a Nexus 5*
- *I tried to launch with gmail (vimeo, buzzfeed tasty ...)*

I don't find why this is not working.

```
Name: Nexus_5X_API_26

CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 26)

Skin: nexus_5x

SD Card: 100M

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 5X

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 26

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-26/google_apis_playstore/x86/

tag.id: google_apis_playstore

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_26

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 420

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 26

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:bc5032b2a871da511332401af3ac6bb0

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 2

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google Play

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to discover and run third-party Android Instant Apps on an emulated device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458271/is-it-possible-to-discover-and-run-third-party-android-instant-apps-on-an-emulat)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Emulators can't talk to the instant apps backends, due to a bug ([see SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250548/invalid-argument-application-credential-header-not-valid-please-fix-the-client)). They only work for local development.
2. Some instant apps (e.g., wish) were published with `targetSdkVersion` < 26, and that's not supported on O devices (just instant apps. Installed apps don't have that restriction.) The developer console now disallows publishing with target < 26, but we continue to serve legacy, pre-restriction apps to pre-O devices. Unfortunately, it means that you'll see some of our popular instant apps stop working when you move to O. If you have access to an O device, try searching for "yummly". I verified that one this morning.

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer. What do you mean about an O device ?

Comment: I mean Oreo, 8.0

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67121438) is probably because "**https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty**" is no longer showing up in Google search results (for reasons unknown), but instead as "https://tasty.co". Their instant app probably only supports the "www.buzzfeed.com" domain.

Try "buzzfeed nifty", I can currently see that.